# How to make Angular Component methods accessible in template but not public?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have an Angular component that contains a text input that calls certain event methods (e.g. onClick, onKeyDown, etc.), but to do that I can't make those methods private. This now exposes these methods.

Is there some technique or way to "hide" these methods from everything except the template?

Comment: template is basically compiled into a piece of typescript which will access your component's fields from outside, so it would need properties to be public for external access

Comment: I don't write an access modifier. Just `doSomething() { }`. This method can be called from the template, but not from outside the component

Comment: @Pieterjan that's what I have now, but it's accessible outside of the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible starting from Ng14, here is PR https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/45823
Basically you can define method as protected on typescript and it will be still accessable in a template

Comment: we are only on 10. IS this just an oversight by Angular in general?